# How can I display facebook user name in react native?

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, authentication, mobile

I can log in into my app with facebook api. I would like to show a welcome message like this: Hi,(facebook name).
How can I do it?
I tried tho showing with: Hi,{displayName} but it didn't works.

//THIS IS THE LOGINSCREEN

```
async loginWithFacebook() {
   const { type, token } = await 
     Expo.Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('717955408626729', 
      { permissions: ['email']['public_profile'] })

    if (type == 'success') {
        const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token)             

        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).catch((error) => 
      {

        })
           }
      }

render() {
    return (

        <View>
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/logo2.png')}
                style={{ height: 280, width: 350, marginTop: -210 }}

            />
            <View>
                <Text>Benvenuto!</Text>

            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.loginWithFacebook()}>
                <Text>Accedi con Facebook</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

    );
}
```

}

Comment: Can you get the price of a facebook name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, if you can get a Facebook name.

```js
const data =  { "displayName": "Mattia Cannavò", "email": null,
   "emailVerified": false, "isAnonymous": false, "lastLoginAt": "1566314114729",
    "phoneNumber": null, "photoURL": "graph.facebook.com/2177408949049079/picture",
     "providerData": Array [ { "displayName": "Mattia Cannavò", 
     "email": "mattiacannavo08@gmail.com", "phoneNumber": null, 
     "photoURL": "graph.facebook.com/2177408949049079/picture", 
     "providerId": "facebook.com", "uid": "2177408949049079", } ] };

<Text>{`Hi ${data.displayName} `}</Text>
```

Comment: I tried to add this code to my homescreen, but it tells me that the facebookname / displayName variable does not exist

Comment: The value I define is an example. You have to get the value.

Comment: here the console output: Object {
  "displayName": "Mattia Cannavò",
  "email": null,
  "emailVerified": false,
  "isAnonymous": false,
  "lastLoginAt": "1566314114729",
  "phoneNumber": null,
  "photoURL": "https://graph.facebook.com/2177408949049079/picture",
  "providerData": Array [
    Object {
      "displayName": "Mattia Cannavò",
      "email": "mattiacannavo08@gmail.com",
      "phoneNumber": null,
      "photoURL": "https://graph.facebook.com/2177408949049079/picture",
      "providerId": "facebook.com",
      "uid": "2177408949049079",
    },
  ],

Comment: how can I get the value?

Comment: thanks, but I don't think this code works for any user, it's not dynamic, if you change your account would you change the name shown?

Comment: This code is dynamic. If the data you get changes, the value changes.

Comment: @MattiaCannavò I just put the result value in the variable that you receive.

Comment: @MattiaCannavò  I did not close it with braces. Fix it again.

Comment: @MattiaCannavò And you shouldn't manually insert data like my answer. I only heard an example.

Comment: continue to give me an error on the penultimate parenthesis square, vs code underlines only that

Comment: @MattiaCannavò If you want to check manually, I have corrected my answer so that no errors are issued. Try my answer.